# Использование предлога "о" и "об" с аббревиатурами

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать: "о СССР" или "об СССР", "о РСФСР" или "об РСФСР", "о НКО" или "об НКО"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всех этих примерах чтение аббревиатуры начинается с нейотированного *гласного звука* "**э**", поэтому предпочтителен предлог "**об**" - в соответствии с общим правилом.

Comment: Понятно. Просто на "Об СССР" "спотыкается" глаз, такая форма кажется простовато-грубоватой. Поэтому решил спросить.